# O365 Subscription per security group collaboration

Tags: azure, entra-id, subscription, microsoft-dfo365

i need some clarification about subscription concept on Azure Active Directory. If an organisation is using multiple O365 subscriptions ( one subscription per security group) ( The security group is representing an entity of the company ). Does it impact collaboration between them for sharepoint for example ? Is one entity going to be considered as a guest when wanting to work on a word file in the other entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Office 365 subscription is not an administrative nor a security boundary. So no, this is not going to impact collaboration between different security groups.